# Система бэкапов на php и cron

Tags: php, резервное-копирование

Коллеги, такая задача возникла.

У нас около 3х десятков сайтов - раскиданы по разным хостингам. Также у нас есть свой сервер, куда мы переодически руками делаем бэкапы и загружаем на наш сервер.

Хочется автоматизации.

Есть много сервисов, наподобии нагиуса и т.д. нам это все не подходит.

Хочу автоматизировать эту систему на php.

Как я вижу эту будущую систему по созданию бэкапов для сайтов по расписанию.

У нас будет некая база, где будут храниться список сайтов, доступы к нему к его БД, и период с которым нужно делать бэкапы.

После чего, в корень каждого сайта, который нужно бэкапить, закидываю скрипт, который создают архив нужных файлов, и полную копию БД.

Далее на крон вешаем скрипт, который будет пробегаться по всем сайтам из нашей базы, дергать скрипты которые создают бэкапы, и перекидывать их на наш сервер.

И сделаем систему миниторинга, когда последний бэкап был, и т.д.

Вопросы:

1) Какой бы метод создания бэкапа посоветовали? Что бы для каждого сайта, я мог задавать папки которые нужно копировать, или которые нужно исключать из архива ?

2) не понятно каким образом из php сделать бэкап БД ?

Comment: Всё это можно bash-скриптом сделать

Comment: а как bash скриптом сделать бэкап БД ?

Comment: mysqldump, ну и ещё ssh и rsync